# Pig MongoLoader exception loading data with UUIDs

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to load data from a Mongo collection that contains fields of data type UUID  in binary form (e.g. BinData(3, "/qHWF5hGQU+w6unYcTQxWw==") ). The job fails with

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2108: \
  Could not determine data type of field: 1423ed53-5064-0000-784b-7bf2e2dd837b".
```

I built mongo-hadoop version 1.1 (from the Master branch). https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop . It works fine except when there are UUIDs. Below is my script and the error. Any ideas?

```
register '/pig/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.9.3.jar';
register '/pig/lib/mongo-hadoop-core_cdh4.3.0-1.1.0.jar';
register '/pig/lib/mongo-hadoop-pig_cdh4.3.0-1.1.0.jar';
a = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost/TestDb.SocialUser'
      USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader();
store a INTO 'a';

2013-07-10 15:03:35,630 [Thread-6] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Map task executor complete.
2013-07-10 15:03:35,632 [Thread-6] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local402930066_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2108: Could not determine data type of field: 1423ed53-5064-0000-784b-7bf2e2dd837b
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:404)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2108: \
    Could not determine data type of field: 1423ed53-5064-0000-784b-7bf2e2dd837b
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.StorageUtil.putField(StorageUtil.java:208)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.StorageUtil.putField(StorageUtil.java:166)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextOutputFormat$PigLineRecordWriter.write(PigTextOutputFormat.java:68)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextOutputFormat$PigLineRecordWriter.write(PigTextOutputFormat.java:44)
  at org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage.putNext(PigStorage.java:296)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:139)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:98)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:558)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map.collect(PigMapOnly.java:48)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:264)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-07-10 15:03:39,235 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
```

Answer (score 2):

The MongoLoader has a method convertBSONtoPigType which is used to convert a type returned by the record reader into a type that is compatible with pig. If the type is not one that is recognised - i.e. including java.util.Date then the method defaults to outputting the object and breaking pig.

If you add a schema to the mongo loader that gives the UUID a pig data type of char array e.g.

load '/mongodb://mongoserver/db.collection' using MongoLoader(myguid:chararray) the underlying java code calls .toString() on the object (in this case the java.util.UUID) and will output a normal UUID.

You could also feasibly change the convertBSONtoPigType method to do the same e.g.

```
public static Object convertBSONtoPigType(final Object o) throws ExecException {
    if (o == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (o instanceof Number || o instanceof String) {
        return o;
    } else if (o instanceof Date) {
        return ((Date) o).getTime();
    } else if (o instanceof ObjectId) {
        return o.toString();
    } else if (o instanceof UUID) {
        return o.toString();
    }
    else if (o instanceof BasicBSONList) {
        BasicBSONList bl = (BasicBSONList) o;
        Tuple t = tupleFactory.newTuple(bl.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < bl.size(); i++) {
            t.set(i, convertBSONtoPigType(bl.get(i)));
        }
        return t;
    } else if (o instanceof Map) {
        //TODO make this more efficient for lazy objects?
        Map<String, Object> fieldsMap = (Map<String, Object>) o;
        HashMap<String, Object> pigMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(fieldsMap.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> field : fieldsMap.entrySet()) {
            pigMap.put(field.getKey(), convertBSONtoPigType(field.getValue()));
        }
        return pigMap;
    } else {
        return o;
    }

}
```

What puzzles me is why the MongoLoader doesn't support the UUID with an unknown schema. Reason is, that UUID / BinData are part of Mongo and widely used.

Maybe it's something they could fix.

Anyway - hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

That is because UUID is not built-in type in Pig. This post gives a solution.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/jAijeRtOG0o